# Laravel 5 - Remove Parameter From All Request Objects at Controller Level

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have URLs that look like:

```
http://example.com/api/user?id=45&name=mike&api_token=2348283
http://example.com/api/project?id=5&description=first&api_token=2348283
etc...
```

In my controllers, I have functions that look like:

```
public function user_get_endpoint(Request $request){

    $request = $request->toArray();
    return UserModel::where($request)->get()->toArray();

}
```

The above will currently break since the `$request` object contains a property called `api_token` which does not exist in the `user` table.  I am using the `api_token` in a middleware to check for authentication.

I can manually unset the `api_token` property in each of my API functions by using `unset($request['api_token']`, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Is there anyway to do this application wide or at a class or controller level?

Comment: You can just do $request = $request->except('api_token')->toArray(); or use its opposite: only.

Comment: Can you show your middleware for the api token?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Perhaps you want [global middleware](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware#global-middleware)?

First arrange for the middleware to run on all routes:

```
// routes.php
$app->middleware([
    App\Http\Middleware\Apitoken::class
]);
```

Then define what the middleware should do:

```
// src/App/Http/Middleware/Apitoken.php
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Apitoken
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        unset($request['api_token']);

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is should be the accepted solution. Laravel even has syntactic sugar for this with `$request->offsetUnset('api_token');`

Comment: this and offsetUnset() is working only for GET and HEAD, see my response that works for all cases...

Comment: In Laravel 8 at least offsetUnset() works also with POST. It's because it doesn't care about the method: `$this->getInputSource()->remove($offset);` (Illuminate\Http\Request)

Answer (score 43):

Laravel provides add and remove functions to add and remove new properties to the request object respectively.

```
 $request->request->add(['api_token' => 'api_token']); // to add new property to $request
    $request->request->remove('api_token'); // to remove property from $request
```

Comment: Just what i needed, to add something i would use the $request->merge([...]) option. But for deleting this works fine

Comment: This doesn't work on Laravel 9.x. (`unset($request['api_token']`) does however).

Comment: request has two public members, `$request->request` is Request body parameters ($_POST).,`$request->query` is Query string parameters ($_GET). You need to call $request->request->remove(),$request->query->remove() for post method

Answer (score 23):

## Method 1

```
$request->except(['key1','key2',....])
```

provides an easy way to skip unwanted keys, similarly

## Method 2

```
$request->only(['key3','key4',....])
```

provides an easy way to skip all others unwanted keys, I find both reasonably good for almost all scenarios

Comment: Warning: This will return an array instead of the Request object.

Answer (score 8):

A solution that works for all HTTP Methods (not only for GET and HEAD) :

```
$except = ['api_token'];
$request = request();
$cleanup = $request->except($except);
$request->query = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag($cleanup);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should send your `api_token` in request headers instead of Uri params.

If you are using Laravel's `auth:api` Middleware for authentication then you can send `api_token` in headers as:

```
$response = $client->request('GET', '/api/user', [
    'headers' => [
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$accessToken,
    ],
]);
```

Then api_token will never come in your Uri params.

Answer (score 0):

As @JanWillem said in the comments you can use `except()` which will remove the params you pass to it:

```
public function user_get_endpoint(Request $request){

    return UserModel::where($request->except('api_token'))->get();
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests#retrieving-input and then scroll down to `Retrieving A Portion Of The Input Data`

Furthermore, you don't have to use `toArray()` with the response as Laravel will automatically do this for you.

Hope this helps!